# Is this set compact? Connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Is this set compact? Connected?

> $S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:z=x^2+y^2+1\}$
>
> for $z\le 1$ this set is not defined, but for $z>1$ we are getting circles!

I imagined this as a bunch of circles over $xy$ plane and connected but not compact set as unbounded. closed set though.
Could anyone give me rigorous treatment?

Comment: It is a bit strange to say that "... for $z\le1$ this set is not defined". *Not defined* usually refers to   a function as $f(x)=1/x$, which is not defined for $x=0$ as it does not give a reasonable output for that input. It is clear, however, what you mean. But then again, it should read "... for $z<1$ ...", $z$ strictly less than $1$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an elliptic (in fact, circular) paraboloid in three-space, with vertex $(0,0,1),$ centered along the positive $z$-axis ($z\ge 1$). Indeed, it is unbounded--just take $x$ large enough, and we can make $(x,0,x^2+1)$ as far from the origin as we like. Note that the function $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y,x^2+y^2+1)$ is a continuous mapping $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3,$ whose image is precisely $S$. What can you say about the continuous image of a connected set (such as the plane)?

**Edit**: As an alternate approach, show that $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y,x^2+y^2+1)$ is in fact a homeomorphism $\Bbb R^2\to S.$ Since the plane is connected and non-compact, then so is $S$.